# This is Error: Protocol error (Network.setCookies): Target closed

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I am using pupeteer to crawl a particular site https://www.example.com

```
puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ['--no-sandbox','--proxy-server='+req.body.proxyIp]}).then(async browser => {
if(req.body.cookieParam){
       var cookieParam = JSON.parse(req.body.cookieParam);
       await page.setCookie(...cookieParam);
}
var url = req.body.url;
const response = await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});

});
```

My cookieParam value:

```
 [{"url":"www.example.com","name":"ak_bmsc","value":"974691EC727E93228E9A2C3722B10D39172F956DE92C0000080D0F5E684D7863;"}]
```

I am getting the below error,

```
This is Error: Protocol error (Network.setCookies): Target closed.
```

Need help to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you remove the setCookie, the goto works?

Comment: I am not getting that error if I remove setCookie.

Comment: Are you sure that what `JSON.parse(req.body.cookieParam);` has the same shape `setCookies` expects?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that there is no `page` target for your cookie, you need to instantiate the page first:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
```